# Switch to a different AWS accounts in the UI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-iam, okta

I currently have AWS configuration set up with my access key id and secret access key (i.e. I see this when going to 'aws configure' in the CLI). I then login through my company's OKTA to then access the AWS UI.

I've just been given access to a new AWS account (lets call it X) that I've been given access to AWS Single Sign-on (SSO) in OKTA for this new account.

What are the steps I need to take in order to access this new account (X)?

Also, I was told that when using SSO it'll give me the option to go to the Management Console or Programatic Access - the Programatic Access will show you iam access key and secret to use, but I still see the previously used account not account (X).

Comment: If you are logging into the AWS console's SSO page, it should show you a list of accounts (and roles) that you have access to. If you only see one account then you probably want to contact whomever administers your account and make sure your user is setup correctly.

Comment: It looks like OKTA is the one granting access to the AWS console. If that's the case I'd consider asking your OKTA admins.